# Ruby on rails. Form for a nested model in a different view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, simple-form, nested-resources

I've been battling this for a while now and I can't figure it out. I have a user model using devise. Users can upload songs, and add youtube videos etc..

I'm trying to let users add/delete songs and videos from the devise `edit registrations` view.

Videos upload fine, but as songs are a nested resource of playlists, which belongs to user, I think I'm getting muddle up.

Music uploads with the same form on it's corresponding page, but not from the devise `registration edit` view.

routes:

```
  devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: "users/registrations", sessions: "users/sessions" }

  resources :videos

  resources :playlists do
    resources :songs
  end
```

Devise registrations controller:

```
   def edit
     @song = Song.new
     @video = Video.new
   end
```

Form in devise edit registrations:

```
<div id="user-music-box">
  <p class="p-details-title"> Upload Music </p>
<%= simple_form_for [@user.playlist, @song] do |f| %>
<%= f.file_field :audio %>
<%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
</div>

<div id="user-video-box">
  <p class="p-details-title"> Add videos </p>
<%= simple_form_for @video do |f| %>
<%= f.input :youtubeurl %>
<%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
</div>
```

As I said, videos (Which is a youtube url string) create and save no problem. The exact same form for songs, basically seems to just update the user `registration`. The song information is shown in the server logs, but no playlist_id is present and nothing gets saved.

Songs controller:

```
def new
      if user_signed_in?
      @song = Song.new
      if current_user.playlist.songs.count >= 5
        redirect_to user_path(current_user)
        flash[:danger] = "You can only upload 5 songs."
      end
      else
     redirect_to(root_url)
     flash[:danger] = "You must sign in to upload songs"
   end
  end

  def create
    @song = current_user.playlist.songs.new song_params
    @song.playlist_id = @playlist.id
    if @song.save
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html {redirect_to user_path(current_user)}
          format.js
        end
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

Playlist.rb

```
class Playlist < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :songs, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :songs
end
```

song.rb

```
class Song < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :playlist
  has_attached_file :audio
  validates_attachment_presence :audio
  validates_attachment_content_type :audio, :content_type => ['audio/mp3','audio/mpeg']
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're passing `songs`/`playlists` through [`accepts_nested_attributes_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) you shouldn't be using `registrations#edit`. I'll detail both ways to achieve what you want below:

---

**Nested Attributes**

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :videos

  has_many :playlists
  has_many :songs, through: :playlists

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :videos
end

#app/models/playlist.rb
class PlayList < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_and_belongs_to_many :songs
end

#app/models/song.rb
class Song < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :playlists
end
```

The importance of this is that to use it properly, you're able to edit the `@user` object directly, passing the nested attributes through the [`fields_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for) helper:

```
#config/routes.rb
devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: "users/registrations", sessions: "users/sessions" }

#app/controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb
class Users::RegistrationsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:edit, :update]

  def edit
    @user = current_user
    @user.playlists.build.build_song
    @user.videos.build
  end

  def update
    @user = current_user.update user_params
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:user, :attributes, videos_attributes: [:youtubeurl], playlists_attributes: [song_ids: [], song_attributes: [:title, :artist, :etc]])
  end
end
```

This will allow you to use:

```
#app/views/users/registrations/edit.html.erb
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :videos do |v| %>
    <%= v.text_field :youtubeurl %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.fields_for :playlists do |p| %>
    <%= p.collection_select :song_ids, Song.all, :id, :name %>
    <%= p.fields_for :song do |s| %>
      <%= f.text_field :title %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %> 
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

This will give you a *single* form, from which you'll be able to create `videos`, `playlists` and `songs` for the `@user`.

---

**Separate**

The other option is to create the object separately.

There is no technical reason for preferring this way over `nested attributes`; you'd do it to make sure you have the routes in the correct order etc.

As a note, you need to remember that routes != model structure. You can have any routes you want, so long as they define a good pattern for your models:

```
# config/routes.rb
authenticated :user do #-> user has to be logged in
  resources :videos, :playlists, :songs #-> url.com/videos/new
end

# app/controllers/videos_controller.rb
class VideosController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @video = current_user.videos.new
  end

  def create
    @video = current_user.videos.new video_params
    @video.save
  end

  private

  def video_params
    params.require(:video).permit(:youtubeurl)
  end
end

# app/views/videos/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @video do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :youtubeurl %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

The above will require the duplication of the `VideosController` for `Playlists` and `Songs`

Comment: Thank you for such an in depth answer. I have tried various forms and have run into many errors. For the time being I have gotten rid of playlists and nested resources with songs. A user now has Videos, and songs. I can successfully create new videos from the registration edit page, as the form fires off the videos controller. When I try to submit the upload song form, the song controller doesn't get fired, just the registrations controller (I do not understand why). For my setup I don't think I really need nested resources, just the ability to use the form in the other controller.

Comment: In the end I have given up. I can't get the songs to create in this way. Videos are fine, and I can't find any differences between the two models so I don't understand why it's not working. For the songs, I have just rendered a form partial in the registrations edit view and it works as desired.

Comment: NO. You must never stop it. You haven't even tried. Are you around now? Let's jump into chat and get it done

Comment: Let me make a chatroom and i'll post the link in here